# Int object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, pygame

I'm building a small game using Pygame and need to extract the current tile the player is standing on and save it to an inventory.

I have looked over the forum for a similar problem, but that didn't help me solve my problem. I have a hard time seeing why it doesn't work.

```
inventory = {
            Elements.DIRT : 0,
            Elements.GRASS : 0,
            Elements.WATER : 0,
            Elements.COAL : 0,
            Elements.ROCK : 0,
            Elements.LAVA : 0
        }

tilemap = [[Elements.DIRT for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in 
range(MAPHEIGHT)]

for rw in range(MAPHEIGHT):
    for cl in range(MAPWIDTH):
        randomNumber = random.randint(0,100)
        if randomNumber == 0:
            tile = Elements.LAVA
        elif randomNumber >= 1 and randomNumber <= 10:
            tile = Elements.COAL
        elif randomNumber >= 11 and randomNumber <= 30:
            tile = Elements.WATER
        elif randomNumber >= 31 and randomNumber <= 75:
            tile = Elements.GRASS
        else:
            tile = Elements.DIRT
        tilemap[rw][cl] = tile


if event.key == K_SPACE:
        #What resource is the player standing on?
        currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1][playerPos[0]]]
        #Player now has 1 more of this resource
        inventory[currentTile] += 1
        #The player is now standing on dirt
        tilemap[playerPos[1][playerPos[0]]] = Elements.DIRT
        print(inventory)
```

I can boot it up but i get the 'int' object has no attribute '`__getitem__`' whenever I tap space. I expected to print the inventory dictionary.

Comment: Which line does it fail on?

Comment: your code is incomplete, read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mismatched brackets on these lines

```
currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1][playerPos[0]]]
```

and

```
tilemap[playerPos[1][playerPos[0]]] = Elements.DIRT
```

It should be:

```
currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
```

and

```
tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]] = Elements.DIRT
```

Previously, you were trying to access the `tilemap` 2D array with the index `playerPos[1][playerPos[0]]`. This in itself was trying to access `playerPos[1]` with index `playerPos[0]`, which is where the error comes from.

Comment: Omg thank you. Sorry for the trivial solution. Been staring at this for too long I think. God damn brackets. Life saver. Thank you

Comment: No worries! Sometimes all it takes is a new set of eyes.